# Task view and Main Apps Panel missing

Tags: xfce, panel

I have a few problems that I believe stems from a single issue.

I have 2 panels on my desktop.

1 on the bottom center with the typical icons - Add Terminal / new note /  file manager / time / etc..
2nd on top with task list.

For some reason I now can see the title bar ( minimize, maximize and exit icons) I never had this before. Before it was just embedded in the screen like a "normal" windows taskbar.  Both panels can now freely move around unlike before being stuck into their positions. I can also see the "Xfce Panel" as actual tasks in my task menu on the top panel, which never occurred before.

I've tried deleting it and reinstating it, but nothing.

Any ideas would be great, Thanks

[image: Desktop]

Version 4.4.2 (XFCE 4.4)

Comment: Did you try locking the widgets?